Azure Data Factory: How to Prevent Data Flow Execution When No File is Found by Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory?
I have an Azure Data Factory pipeline structured as follows:

Copy Activity: Searches for a file on an SFTP server using a specific wildcard and timestamp, and moves it to Blob Storage.
Data Flow: On success of copy activity, Retrieves the file from Blob Storage, compares its contents with an SQL table, and copies non-matching rows to the SQL table.

The problem is that even when there is no matching file on the SFTP server, the pipeline still triggers the Data Flow.
How can I configure the Copy Activity to prevent the Data Flow from executing when no file is found and moved to Blob Storage?

This could be an "alternative" solution:
check the file exists before triggering the Dataflow with a Get Metadata activity?
General flow
The flow will look like this:

Dataset
Having a dataset with some parameter (ADLS Gen2 Parquet in my case, but it could be anything) allows you to dynamically populate your file name.
Parameters

Connection

This way you can dynamically populate your file name.
Metadata activity
The configuration of the get metadata activity will be pretty simple:

You can add variables at will to dinamically populate the filename/path
If condition
The Dataflow will be triggered based on the file exsitance with this expression @activity('Get Metadata1').output.exists

Edit 1
Following request: dinamically created file name
Let's say we want to dinamically set the filename property of the dataset. Click on add "add dynamic content"

Using a variable
Lets say we want to dynamically set the output filename of the sftp retrieved file.
1. Add a Variable
Add a variable to the pipeline


2. Add a set Variable activity

write your dynamic expression
3. Consume the variable
Consume the variable value in the dataset parameter

The updated flow


Thank you, Gam! In the GetMetadata activity, could you access the file name dynamically instead of hardcoding it?

Yes, sure, the file name could be dynamic. You can: 1. Use the output of another activity (like the copy activity data) 2. Dinamically create a variable. The main "trick" is to have created the dataset with parameters. I'll provide you an example

Hi Gam! Why are you hardcoding the filename to 'test.parquet'? From my perspective, this is how i want the flow: 1. Copy activity to take the csv file from SFTP and move to Storage container; 2. Get the name of the file moved and the size or row count of the file ; 3. If the row count > 0 then 4. execute a data flow. Im a bit confused by your flow. could you please clarify?

test.parquet is just the default value. The effective name of the file has to be set using the set variable activity. There you can write an expression to se the file name as you like
